# AndroidViewClient view.getvisibility() returns -1

Tags: android, visibility, androidviewclient

When I run following code, although I declare the view as visible, it always returns -1:

```
et = vc.findViewById('com.hamed.android:id/editText1')
time.sleep(2)
print et.getVisibility()
```

I check getVisibility() method and see that it returns -1 when an exception arise in getting visibility property. Where is my fault?

Comment: did you use this view in your setContent() ?

Comment: No, I didn't. How can it raise exception?!

Comment: if you don't set that view is it really visible ? Try setting it and then check what your code returns.

Comment: I run my android application and work with it. The view is visible but I don't know why AVC raises exception!

Comment: What if you use et = vc.findViewByIdOr Raise('com.hamed.android:id/editText1') and what if you perform refresh (dump) again after time.sleep(2) and then et = vc.findViewByIdOr Raise('com.hamed.android:id/editText1') again? (Maybe your et = vc.findViewById('com.hamed.android:id/editText1') returns None and maybe the view disappear etc after the sleep)

Comment: Also try just `print et` to see what `et` contains

Comment: @dtmilano: It prints out: View[ class=android.widget.EditText index=2 selected=false NAF=true clickable=true package=com.mkyong.android text= long-clickable=true enabled=true bounds=((0, 128), (320, 176)) content-desc= focusable=true focused=true uniqueId=id/no_id/9 checkable=false resource-id=com.mkyong.android:id/editText1 password=false class=android.widget.EditText checked=false scrollable=false ]   parent=android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: @Eliyahu: Thanks. but no result for your suggestions.

Comment: There's no point in sleeping after finding the View

Answer (score 0):

**UIAutomator** does not return **INVISIBLE** Views in its dump. That's why they disappear, if they were **VISIBLE** before.